# Jquery show a dynamically loaded div

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a bunch of DIVS, that were loaded dynamically by a jquery AJAX call.   The DIVS all have a anchor with a class of .more_info and an id of info-xxx (where xxx is the product id).  There is a hidden div with the id of infoxxx which I want to show when the link is clicked.

My code:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.more_info' ,function(){
    var dealid = ($(this).attr('id')); 

    $("#info"+dealid).show(1000);  

  });
```

but the div (infoxxx) doesn't show. I'm guessing that there is there another way to access that div because it was loaded dynamically?

Comment: Just for clarification, do you get the correct `dealid` when you use `console.log(dealid)`? You just said that the `id` attribute has a format of `info-123`, so the value of `dealid` will be `info-123` rather than `123`, is that correct?

Comment: when taking the `.attr('id')` why would you add `#info` in the selector for the `.show()`, im assuming you will only need a `#` or nothing at all except for the `dealid`

Comment: Thanks guys, both these comments pointed me in the right direction.   The original coder was faffing around with id's that weren't needed I've simplified it just to the the dealid (without the info) and it's working as planned.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the details provided the dealid produced from ($(this).attr('id')) will be of the form   info-xxx so when you try

```
$("#info"+dealid).show(1000);
```

it will be like

```
$("#infoinfo-xxx").show(1000);
```

So get the correct id by replacing the info- text

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.more_info' ,function(){
    var dealid = ($(this).attr('id')).replace("info-",""); 

    $("#info"+dealid).show(1000);  

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the HTML accurately but the main idea is this:

> ```
> var prodID = dealID.split('-').pop();
> ```

`dealID` is the pattern `info-xxx`

Use `split('-')` at the hyphen and endup with an array of 2 elements `['info', xxxx]`

Then chain `pop()` to the `split()` method and get `xxxx` on return.

---

### Demo

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.more_info', function() {
  var dealID = ($(this).attr('id'));

  var prodID = dealID.split('-').pop();

  $("#info" + prodID).show(1000);

});
```

```css
.more_info::after {
  content: attr(class)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href='#/' id='info-1234' class='more_info'></a>
</div>
<input id='info1234' hidden>

<div>
  <a href='#/' id='info-1359' class='more_info'></a>
</div>
<input id='info1359' hidden>

<div>
  <a href='#/' id='info-6911' class='more_info'></a>
</div>
<input id='info6911' hidden>

<div>
  <a href='#/' id='info-5227' class='more_info'></a>
</div>
<input id='info5227' hidden>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```